# Extracting XML data with ColdFusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm trying to get a list of IDs to populate a few tables from [this XML file](http://cdn.easf.www.easports.com/fifa/football-club/static/wpp10legacy/plugin/futFifaUltimateTeamPlugin/assets/flash/xml/localization/messages.en_GB.xml). 
I've created the functions to do the database inserts in ColdFusion so I'm looking for a way to get the desired content from the XML file.

I'm struggling with trying to get the specific content for each item type (Leagues, Nationalities) as the node names are 'weird' - certainly to me. For example I want to get the 2013 leagues which come under the nodes:

```
 <trans-unit resname="global.leagueabbr15.2013.league50">
   <source>SPL</source>
 </trans-unit>
```

where the "league50" is the ID I want and ("SPL") is the text value I want to store.

How could I loop round each 2013.league to get the ID and source value?

**(Update from comments)**

I've had a look at XML search but the xml doesn't seem to be structured very well and so the I need to search after a certain part of the resname. (i.e. In the following xml I need to get the ID at the end -> `global.leagueabbr15.2013.league[ID]`.

```
<trans-unit resname="global.leagueabbr15.2013.league1"> 
    <source>Superliga</source> 
</trans-unit> 
<trans-unit resname="global.leagueabbr15.2013.league10"> 
     <source>Eredivisie</source> 
</trans-unit> 
<trans-unit resname="global.leagueabbr15.2013.league13"> 
     <source>Barclays PL</source> 
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: What have you thusfar tried?

Comment: Rather than linking to a 1Mb file, it might help if you posted just some of the relevant XML you're talking about in your question

Comment: To get you started look at the ColdFusion functions [XmlParse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e90.html) and [XmlSearch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78e8.html).

Comment: The answer I posted gives you every block, you just need to change to output to a conditional checking the league name.

Comment: But how would I check the league name? Can I use a wildcard as per my update above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where xmlData represents pulling the file into a variable. This will spit out all of the blocks underneath. Just change the output to a test for the resname being the league you wanted. You could then reference the source.xmltext under the loop block as well.

```
<cfscript>
xmlContent  = xmlParse(xmlData);
subSet  = xmlSearch(xmlContent,'/xliff/file/body/trans-unit/');

for(i=1; i LTE arrayLen(subSet); i++) {
writeoutput(subSet[i].XMLAttributes.resname & "<br />");
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: But how would I check the league name? Can I use a wildcard as per my update above?

Comment: Instead of the writeoutput just do an if on the same var IS whatever league name.